# Storing unsinged char?

Tags: c++, char, store, unsigned

I'm trying to get the mac address of a user, then store it in a string. I've got the mac address get function down, however I'm having a bit of trouble storing the final value of the mac address into a string. Can anybody help out?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <rpc.h>
#include <rpcdce.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "rpcrt4.lib")

using namespace std;


static void PrintMACaddress(unsigned char MACData[])
{
    printf("%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X\n", MACData[0], MACData[1], MACData[2], MACData[3], MACData[4], MACData[5]);
}

static void GetMACaddress(void)
{
    unsigned char MACData[6];

    UUID uuid;
    UuidCreateSequential(&uuid);

    for (int i=2; i<8; i++)
        MACData[i - 2] = uuid.Data4[i];

    PrintMACaddress(MACData);
}

int main()
{
    GetMACaddress();
    system("pause");
}
```

Basiclly, I need the final result into a string value
Sorry if this is too broad.

Comment: Where exactly you got a problem?

Comment: In converting the final result into a string.

Comment: What is the current output of your program?

Comment: @tivn It currently outputs your mac uuid, ex: XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX

Comment: So the output is correct and you just want it converted into a std::string?

Comment: @tivn Yes, exactly that. I want to be able to use it later in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use snprintf() function to convert to string:

```
char buffer[1024];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X",
MACData[0], MACData[1], MACData[2], MACData[3], MACData[4], MACData[5]);

std::string str = buffer;
```

Comment: using cout << str << end; didn't return anything, but using buffer worked. Is that ok?

Comment: That's weird. What if you change `snprintf` to `_snprintf` ?

Comment: I had to use `_snprintf` originally.

Comment: How about `std::string str = std::string(buffer);`

Comment: Still blank return. It's ok though, buffer works fine for me. Thanks for the help